# C: Problem using pointers to update variable in main from different function

Tags: c, pointers, scope

I'm new with pointers and C. When I first print Q I get 0 as expected. Once I've then updated Q to the value of q I print it out again and get -1 as expect. However, when I then print Q out as part of the main function I am getting 0 again. What am I doing wrong with my pointers?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void decompose(double k, int *S, int *Q, double *F);

int main(){
    double k, F;
    int S, Q;
    k = 0.75;
    decompose(k, &S, &Q, &F);
    /*Printed third*/
    printf("%g\n", k);
    printf("%i\n", S);
    printf("%i\n", Q);
    printf("%g\n", F);
    return(0);
}

void decompose(double k, int *S, int *Q, double *F){
    if (k > 0){
        *S = 1;
    }
    else{
        *S = -1;
        k = k * -1;
    }
    
    int b = 2, q = 0;
    if (k > 1){
        while (pow(b, q) < k){
            q = q + 1;
        }
        q = q - 1;
    }
    else if (k < 1){
        while (pow(b, q) > k){
            q = q - 1;
        }
        /*Printed first*/
        printf("%i\n", q);
        printf("%i\n", *Q);
    }
    *Q = q;
    /*Printed second*/
    printf("%i\n", q);
    printf("%i\n", *Q);
    *F = frexp(k, Q);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`frexp` changes the `int` pointed to by its second argument. Since you are passing `Q` for the second argument, it changes `*Q`.

When you call it, the first argument, `k`, has the value .75. `frexp` sets the `int` pointed to by the second argument to the exponent of two needed to scale the first argument to the interval [½, 1). Since .75 is already between ½ and 1, .75 = .75•2<sup>0</sup>, so `*Q` is set to zero.